# How to display content of a file with taking account of other file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, awk

I have the **file1** with the following content

```
{"name":"clio5", "value":"13"}
{"name":"citroen_c4", "value":"23"}
{"name":"citroen_c3", "value":"12"}
{"name":"golf4", "value":"16"}
{"name":"golf3", "value":"8"}
```

And I have the **file2** with the following content

```
{"name":"clio5", "value":"14"}
{"name":"citroen_c4", "value":"25"}
{"name":"golf4", "value":"18"}
```

I want to execute a shell command in order to display the content of the **file1** and the **file2**. if a `name` exist in both **file1** and **file2** so I want to display only the related line of the **file2**.

So the output should look like this:

```
$command taking account file1 file2
{"name":"clio5", "value":"14"}
{"name":"citroen_c4", "value":"25"}
{"name":"citroen_c3", "value":"12"}
{"name":"golf4", "value":"18"}
{"name":"golf3", "value":"8"}
```

The command should not edit **file1** neither **file2**

**Edit**

The **file1** and **file2** have exactelly the same content format:

```
{"name":"any", "value":"xx"}
```

The command should be as simple as possible

The command could contains `grep`, `sed`, `awk`

Comment: "if line exists" should probably explain a little clearer, that it's not if the "same line" exists, but just a line with the same "name" :)

Comment: @SvendHansen yes exactelly

Comment: I think my solution _might_ work now, if the order of the output isn't important :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way with `awk`:

```
awk -F"[:,]" '
NR==FNR { name[$2]=$0;next }
($2 in name) { delete name[$2]; print $0 }
END { for (left in name) print name[left] }' file1 file2
```

#### Test:

```
$ head file*
==> file1 <==
{"name":"clio5", "value":"13"}
{"name":"citroen_c4", "value":"23"}
{"name":"citroen_c3", "value":"12"}
{"name":"golf4", "value":"16"}
{"name":"golf3", "value":"8"}

==> file2 <==
{"name":"clio5", "value":"14"}
{"name":"citroen_c4", "value":"25"}
{"name":"golf4", "value":"18"}

$ awk -F"[:,]" '
NR==FNR { name[$2]=$0;next }
($2 in name) { delete name[$2]; print $0 }
END { for (left in name) print name[left] }' file1 file2
{"name":"clio5", "value":"14"}
{"name":"citroen_c4", "value":"25"}
{"name":"golf4", "value":"18"}
{"name":"golf3", "value":"8"}
{"name":"citroen_c3", "value":"12"}
```

Comment: Clean & simple solution. +1

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use `join` to join both files on the name field and then use `awk` to change the value. This is shown below:

```
$ join -t, -a1 <(sort file1) <(sort file2) | awk -F, -vOFS=, '{if($3){$2=$3;NF-=1}}1' | sed 's/new_value/value/g'
{"name":"citroen_c3", "value":"12"}
{"name":"citroen_c4", "value":"25"}
{"name":"clio5", "value":"14"}
{"name":"golf3", "value":"8"}
{"name":"golf4", "value":"18"}
```

`join` requires both files to be sorted on the join key.

---

Alternatively, if ordering matters to you, you can use a loop to read each line and then grep the second file for the new value. This is shown below:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    if [[ $line =~ name\":\"([^\"]*)\" ]]
    then
        name=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        newVal=$(grep "\"name\":\"$name\"" file2 | sed 's/^.*"\([^"]\+\)"}$/\1/g')
        if [[ -z $newVal ]]
        then
            echo "$line"
        else
            echo "{\"name\":\"$name\", \"value\":\"$newVal\"}"
        fi
    fi
done < file1
```

Output:

```
{"name":"clio5", "value":"14"}
{"name":"citroen_c4", "value":"25"}
{"name":"citroen_c3", "value":"12"}
{"name":"golf4", "value":"18"}
{"name":"golf3", "value":"8"}
```

Comment: I want something simple. I update my question to explain more.

Comment: I do not have join in my linux

Answer (score 1):

The input looks like JSON. Using a proper tool, the [JSON](http://p3rl.org/JSON) library for Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use JSON qw(from_json to_json);

my %hash;

for my $file (qw/file1 file2/) {
    open my $FH, '<', $file or die $!;
    while (<$FH>) {
        my $j = from_json($_);
        $hash{$j->{name}} = $j->{value} // $j->{new_value};
    }
}

while (my ($name, $value) = each %hash) {
    print to_json({name => $name, value => $value}), "\n";
}
```

It reads the two files, overwriting the values when reading the second one. For me, the output is not exactly what you expected:

```
{"value":"14","name":"clio5"}
{"value":"18","name":"golf4"}
{"value":"25","name":"citroen_c4"}
{"value":"8","name":"golf3"}
{"value":"12","name":"citroen_c3"}
```

As JSON goes, it is equivalent to your expected output, so if you always use the appropriate libraries, you will not notice the difference. If not, you have to tweak the code some more.

Or, if you really want to use sed:

```
sed 's%\({"name":"[^"]*", \)"new_value":\("[^"]*"\)}%s/\1"value.*/\1"value":\2}/%' file2 \
    | sed -f- file1
```

The first sed invocation translates *file2* into a sed script that replaces the old values in *file1*.

Comment: formatting is easy to fix, just replace `to_json` with your custom format. a more serious problem could be that it doesn't preserve order... but the OP didn't specify what he wants. let's wait.

Comment: I want something simple. I update my question to explain more.

Comment: @MOHAMED: I added a "simple" sed solution.

Comment: the sed command return error: `sed: can't open '-': No such file or directory`

Comment: @MOHAMED: Then redirect the output of the first `sed` command to a temp file with `> temp_file`, then use `-f temp_file` instead in the second `sed`.

Comment: no output and I checked tempfile, it contains lines like this: `s/{"name":"clio5", "value.*/{"name":"clio5", "value":"14"}/`

Comment: @MOHAMED: Correct. Now `sed -f temp_file file1`.

Comment: it work only if there is no special charachers in the values. if there is special charachters in the file2 `{"name":"citroen_c4", "new_value":"2\"4\"5"}` then the command will cause error

Comment: @MOHAMED: That's why I recommended Perl and JSON.

Comment: I still think my `sort` solution works, and is even simpler than the `sed` one :D

Answer (score 1):

A simple change to my solution, and it seems to work:

Is the order of the output important? Otherwise you could do this, using `sort`:

```
cat file2 file1 | sort -u -s --key=1
```

The change is adding `--key=1`. This means it will sort on the first column (up to first whitespace) of each line. `-s` makes it not use sorting on the rest of the line, when the other sort finds two equals. The order of the files determines which file's lines will be used when there is a match.

This will output the result sorted alphabetically. It looks like the input already is, in which case it should exactly what you describe (I believe). Otherwise, it *would* change the order of the lines (to be sorted). Not sure if that's a problem?