# Replace a line in a file with a string

Tags: linux, shell, sed, awk

I have a file `file1` with the following content

```
{"name":"clio5", "value":"13"}
{"name":"citroen_c4", "value":"23"}
{"name":"citroen_c3", "value":"12"}
{"name":"golf4", "value":"16"}
{"name":"golf3", "value":"8"}
```

I want to look for the line which contains the word `clio5` and then replace the found line by the following string

```
string='{"name":"clio5", "value":"1568688554"}'
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use shell scripting tools for handling JSON values. Wouldn't it be better to use a dedicated JSON parser.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display content of a file with taking account of other file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17784369/how-to-display-content-of-a-file-with-taking-account-of-other-file)

Comment: @choroba it's another kind of question I want to replace a string into a file.

Comment: The upate you made completely changes the question. Before you were asking to find "clio5" as a "name", now you want to find the word "clio5" anywhere on the line so it could be part of a multi-word name, or it could be part of a value or anything else.  How do you define a "word"?  Is that REALLY what you want? If so post some more representative sample input and expected output.

Comment: Maybe I'm not getting something, but why isn't this trivial using sed? i.e. `sed 's/.*clio5.*/{"name":"clio5", "value":"1568688554"}/'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you extract the `name` part from your `$string` as

```
NAME=`echo $string | sed 's/[^:]*:"\([^"]*\).*/\1/'`
```

Then, use the `$NAME` to replace the string as

```
sed -i "/\<$NAME\>/s/.*/$string/" file1
```

Comment: That will not work if NAME can be part of other names (e.g. if "clio5" and "clio55" both appear in the input), nor if NAME can contain RE metacharacters like "." or "*". The OP said he wanted a string comparison, not an RE comparison.

Comment: No, that just fixed the part of it about partial matches on longer words, it doesn't fix the issue about RE metacharacters. You just can't use sed for this as sed CANNOT do a string comparison. It also has an issue I hadn't noticed before in that it will do word splittling, globbing, and will convert all sequences of white space into single chars.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ string='{"name":"clio5", "value":"1568688554"}'
$ awk -F'"(:|, *)"' -v string="$string" 'BEGIN{split(string,s)} {print ($2==s[2]?string:$0)}' file
{"name":"clio5", "value":"1568688554"}
{"name":"citroen_c4", "value":"23"}
{"name":"citroen_c3", "value":"12"}
{"name":"golf4", "value":"16"}
{"name":"golf3", "value":"8"}

$ string='{"name":"citroen_c3", "value":"1568688554"}'
$ awk -F'"(:|, *)"' -v string="$string" 'BEGIN{split(string,s)} {print ($2==s[2]?string:$0)}' file
{"name":"clio5", "value":"13"}
{"name":"citroen_c4", "value":"23"}
{"name":"citroen_c3", "value":"1568688554"}
{"name":"golf4", "value":"16"}
{"name":"golf3", "value":"8"}
```

Updated the above based on @dogbane's comment so it will work even if the text contains `"`s. It will still fail if the text can contain `":"` (with appropriate escapes) but that seems highly unlikely and the OP can tell us if it's a valid concern.

Comment: This won't work if the name contains double-quotes. e.g. `string='{"name":"citroen_c4 \"foo\"", "value":"1568688554"}'`.

Comment: That's true, I've updated my answer to handle it, thanks for catching that. @MOHAMED - tell us if there is still an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use awk like this:

```
awk -v str="$string" -F '[,{}:]+' '{
  split(str, a);
  if (a[3] ~ $3)
     print str;
  else print
}' file.json
```

Comment: @anubhava, is it possible to redirect the output result to the file.json?

Comment: Yes you can do: `awk '...' file.json > _temp && mv _temp file.json`